# Ruby says IOError: Closed stream?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ioerror

I have following issue with my program only on 1 Linux(14.04.3) machine out of 3, It is running Ruby 1.9.3.
This program runs without errors on all other Linux machines(14.04.3).
Any help appreciated.

**program**

```
def test_image_data
(0..@ptif_wac_true.pages-1).each do |pagenum|
  @ptif_wac_true.page = pagenum
  @ptif_wac_test.page = pagenum
  [[0,0],[@ptif_wac_true.x_tiles-1,@ptif_wac_true.y_tiles-1]].each do |tile_x,tile_y|
    tile_true = @ptif_wac_true.get_tile(tile_y,tile_x).open.read

    tmp_true = Tempfile.new("tile_true_#{pagenum}_#{tile_x}_#{tile_y}", @tmp_dir)
    begin
      tmp_true.write(tile_true)
    ensure
      tmp_true.close
    end

    tile_test = @ptif_wac_test.get_tile(tile_y,tile_x).open.read

    tmp_test = Tempfile.new("tile_test_#{pagenum}_#{tile_x}_#{tile_y}", @tmp_dir)
    begin
      tmp_test.write(tile_test)
    ensure
      tmp_test.close
    end

    template = "convert '#{tmp_true.path}' '#{tmp_test.path}' -compose Difference -composite -colorspace gray -format '%[fx:mean*100]' info:"
    assert_operator( `#{template}`.to_f,:<=, 0.55, "Page: #{pagenum} TileX #{tile_x} TileY #{tile_y} does not look right!")

    tmp_true.unlink #lets cleanup after done, its a good practice
    tmp_test.unlink
  end
end
```

What can I do fix this issue?
Below is the error i'm getting.

**Error:**

> ```
> test_image_data(Pnm2ptifTest):
>  IOError: closed stream
> ./test_pnm2ptif:155:in `read'
> ./test_pnm2ptif:155:in `block (2 levels) in test_image_data'
> ./test_pnm2ptif:154:in `each'
> ./test_pnm2ptif:154:in `block in test_image_data'
> ./test_pnm2ptif:151:in `each'
> ./test_pnm2ptif:151:in `test_image_data'
> ```

Comment: The error is on this line right?
`tile_true = @ptif_wac_true.get_tile(tile_y,tile_x).open.read`

I'm not sure what class that object is, but try using a debugger and find out what the `@ptif_wac_true.get_tile(tile_y,tile_x)` object is, what happens when you open.

Also, try using `open do |f| f.read; end` instead of `open.read` just in case.

Comment: IOError means that this is unlikely (albeit not impossible) to be a syntax issue. There is a number of issues you need to examine. Are your 3 systems identical? Can you check your syslogs? What kind of stream is this? Are all the necessary dev packages installed on the misbehaving system?